# Upgrading PrimeFaces 3.4.2 to 5.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to PrimeFaces and I have a little task to upgrade project's PrimeFaces from 3.4.2 to 5.1. I have tried to look for a step by step tutorial on how to do it but I couldn't find anything. Do you guys have any experience doing that? Could you please tell give me a step by step tutorial how to upgrade it properly before I go totally wrong way?

```
<jsf-myfaces.version>2.1.10</jsf-myfaces.version>
<primefaces.version>3.4.2</primefaces.version>
<cxf.version>2.7.10</cxf.version>
<spring-version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring-version>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

I have tried few tutorials but without any luck.

Comment: This probably does not qualify as answer but maybe the official migration guide helps: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. Didn't look at the date, the questions just popped up in my queue